# Only fire click on elements in the parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the element `li.bc-cate-has-child.first` when I click on `a.bc-pagination-next`, and hide it when I click on `a.bc-pagination-next`.

Below script works, but the click will show/hide all the matching elements in both containers, how can I keep the click to just affect the elements in the parent container?

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bc-list-wrap').each(function () {
        $("a.bc-pagination-next").click(function () {
            $("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").hide();
        })

        $("a.bc-pagination-prev").click(function () {
            $("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").show();
        })
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bc-list-wrap">
    <ul class="bc-list bc-ul bc-list-not-standard">
        <li class="bc-cate-has-child first" style="display: none;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bc-pagination">
        <a class="bc-pagination-next">next</a>
        <a class="bc-pagination-prev">prev</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bc-list-wrap">
    <ul class="bc-list bc-ul bc-list-not-standard">
        <li class="bc-cate-has-child first" style="display: none;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bc-pagination">
        <a class="bc-pagination-next">next</a>
        <a class="bc-pagination-prev">prev</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use current element context i.e. `this` and traverse DOM to target the desired element and then perform required operation on it.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to travese up to common ancestor afterwards [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) can be used to target the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bc-list-wrap').on("click", "a.bc-pagination-next", function () {
        $(this).closest('.bc-list-wrap').find("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").hide();
    })

    $('.bc-list-wrap').on("click", "a.bc-pagination-prev", function () {
        $(this).closest('.bc-list-wrap').find("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").show();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$(this).closest('.bc-list-wrap').find("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").hide();
```

And

```
$(this).closest('.bc-list-wrap').find("li.bc-cate-has-child.first").show()
```

Reference [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bc-list-wrap').each(function () {
        $('a.bc-pagination-next').click(function () {
            $(this).parents('.bc-list-wrap').find('li.bc-cate-has-child.first').hide();
        })

        $('a.bc-pagination-prev').click(function () {
            $(this).parents('.bc-list-wrap').find('li.bc-cate-has-child.first').show();
        })
});
```